# Changing background url path via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Getting background of a section using `$('section').css('background');`

The result I get in the console looks like this:

*rgb(13, 25, 73) url("http://website.com/image_01_closed.jpg") no-repeat scroll 50% 100% / contain padding-box border-box*

Wondering how can I change url's path from _closed.jpg to _opened.jpg ?
Got many sections so want to change it for any image with _closed in it's name.

Comment: you can easily do by changing a class. create 2 class one for _closed.jpg and another for _opened.jpg and on based on your condition just toggle the class

Comment: It will be helpful if you provide your html and java-script code

Comment: Want my JS to work with all image names so simple toogle with the new path to the image is not an option.

There is too much code to upload. Just want to know how can I manipulate the string I get to achieve my goal.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this,

```
var el = document.getElementById("section_id").style.backgroundImage;
    if(el == "url(close.jpg)") { // full value is provided
       el.style.backgroundImage = "url(/link/open.png)"; // change it
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found working solution with this code:

```
var url = $('section').css('background-image');
var res = url.replace("_closed", "_opened");
$('section').css('background-image',res);
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#btn').click(function(){
$('div').toggleClass('close')
})
})
```

```css
.open{
height: 200px;
width:200px;
background-image: url("http://s5.tinypic.com/35jbaqq_th.jpg");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-color: #cccccc;
background-position: center;

}
.close{
height: 200px;
width:200px;
background-image: url("http://s6.tinypic.com/vg04ft_th.jpg");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-color: #fff;
background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='btn'>change BG</button>
<br/>
<br/>
<div class='open'>
Content
</div>
<br/>
<div class='open'>
Content
</div>
```